# SCSS &- multiple string options

Tags: css, sass

I have never used .scss files before and am trying to make a simple change.

```
&-tabbed {
  //some code
}
&-list {
   //some other code
}
&-tableau {
  //some code
}
```

I want to make the third option the same as the first without having a new class. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You mean you want the third class to have the same styles as the first class ? Or what exactly you want to say ?

Comment: yes same style as the first class, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@extend` it will copy all the styles and give to the class you want

```
.wrapper {
  &-tabbed {
    color: red;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  &-list {
     //some other code
  }
  &-tableau {
    @extend .wrapper-tabbed
  }
}
```

the result will be like that

```
.wrapper-tabbed, .wrapper-tableau {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

You also can use **placeholder selectors**

```
%placeholder {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1rem;
}


.wrapper {
  &-tabbed {
    @extend %placeholder;
  }
  &-list {
     //some other code
  }
  &-tableau {
    @extend  %placeholder;
  }
}
```

the result will be the same

```
.wrapper-tabbed, .wrapper-tableau {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

**MIXIN usage** **Notice** that it will render the styles 2 times its not extending it

```
@mixin styles{
  color: red;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.wrapper {
  &-tabbed {
    @include styles;
  }

  &-tableau {
    @include styles;  
  }
}
```

result will be like that

```
.wrapper-tabbed {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.wrapper-tableau {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Mixin.

```
@mixin mixinname{

width:100px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #000;

}

Add this mixin
&-tabbed {

  @include mixinname;

}

&-tableau {
      @include mixinname;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a mixing or any special code for that. Just separate the rules with `,` as you do in common `css`:

```
&-tabbed,
&-tableau {
  //some code
}
&-list {
 //some other code
}
```

Comment: and in case he want to have more styles for 1 of this classes then he have to define the class again to not mix up all styles together

Comment: @AdelElkhodary in that case it will be pointed in the question. The question refers to the same code for both selectors.